# List of List of Dictionary to MultiIndex Dataframe with Values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a list of list of dictionary that I would like to be transformed into a dataframe but I can't seem to make my code work.

Currently, this is my example list

```
eglist = [[{'var1': False, 'name_id': 23, 'team': 0 , 'order':0},
           {'var1': False, 'name_id': 24, 'team': 0 , 'order':1}, 
           {'var1': False, 'name_id': 1, 'team': 0 , 'order':2}],
          [{'var1': False, 'name_id': 23, 'team': 0 , 'order':0},
           {'var1': False, 'name_id': 24, 'team': 0 , 'order':1}, 
           {'var1': False, 'name_id': 1, 'team': 0 , 'order':2}]]
```

The larger list has around 9000 lists of dictionary.

And I would like it to be transformed into

```
dfframe =  
      Order 0               Order 1                        Order 2 
0     var1  name_id  team   var1     name_id    team       var1   name_id    team
      False     23      0   False       24        0        False     1        0

1     var1  name_id  team   var1     name_id    team       var1   name_id    team`
      False     23      0   False       24        0        False     1        0
```

Any help would be great! I am a beginner and hence a little unsure on how to proceed.

This is a repost of a deleted post as I posted unrelated code in that post.

Comment: Can you share your current code? A [mcve] would be great.

Comment: Sure. But I think its way too long in its current format, its 9000 rows. I was parsing matches from the Valve API. Weirdly enough my data when applied with the method you provided gave me an error:`for row in L:
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`

Comment: For your latest error, check `type(L)`. It's probably a float rather than a list.

Comment: Thanks for the help! There were some missing data in the list! Was wondering why it could never work. Is there a way  to replace the missing data with `.append` for the code to work?

Comment: I'm not sure. Depends where the data is missing, e.g. is a key missing? You might have to ask another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow these steps:

1. Use `collections.defaultdict` to aggregate data by `order` key.
2. Convert to a single dataframe using `pd.concat` over `axis=1`.
3. Add level to columns via `pd.MultiIndex`.

Here's a demo:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# aggregate data by order
d = defaultdict(list)
for L in eglist:
    for row in L:
        d[row['order']].append([row['var1'], row['name_id'], row['team']])

# convert to dataframe
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(v, columns=[f'{k}_var1', f'{k}_name_id', f'{k}_team'])
                for k, v in d.items()], axis=1)

# convert columns to MultiIndex
headers = [('Order '+col.split('_')[0], col.split('_')[-1]) for col in df.columns]
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(headers, names=['Team', 'Data'])

print(df)

Team Order 0          Order 1          Order 2        
Data    var1  id team    var1  id team    var1 id team
0      False  23    0   False  24    0   False  1    0
1      False  23    0   False  24    0   False  1    0
```